# debian package cross build error - dpkg-shlibdeps error couldn't find library

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies, shared-library

I am building a debian installer package on Ubuntu 16.04, to be installed on my Arm64 system, however am having difficulty resolving library dependencies during the build.

I run the following debuild command

```
debuild -us -uc --host-arch arm64
```

and get errors such as the following

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgcc_s.so.1
```

For info, my linux kernel is as follows

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-66-generic #75~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 14:01:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Naturally, I would expect the dependent libraries to be present on the target system but would like build the package without the need for the libraries on the build machine.

I don't want to disable shlibdeps because this plugin ensures ldconfig gets called during installation.

I'd be grateful for advise on how to call shlibdeps when cross-building.

UPDATE :
I'm not actually building the binaries, only creating an installer for the binaries. Perhaps this is not convention and the solution would be to ensure the dependent libraries are present on the machine creating the installer package.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the commands you’re running to build the package?

Comment: can you add the output of `uname -a ` ?